# what is the benefit behind provider or BLoC pattern?

Tags: flutter

We have a lot of State management solutions like providers and BLoC pattern. But, why do we need them?. why can't I create a file called 'data.dart' and import this file(data.dart) wherever i need, and make changes to the variables and objects in this file(data.dart)? Does this pattern has any downsides?

Comment: I would recommend you to watch this talk - [Pragmatic State Management in Flutter Google I/O'19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I)

Answer (score 0):

State management solutions are needed for datas that changes.

Imagine having data.dart file that has a variable

`String text = 'abc';`

And you have a Text() widget called TextA that takes in text variable as input.
This widget would initially display abc

now you have this function called

```
void changeText(){
text = 'cba';
}
```

how would this function tell TextA to rebuild because the value of text has already been changed?

of course you can use setState((){}); as long as the function is part of TextA,

but what if the Widget is ButtonA?

Answer (score 0):

similar to StatefulWidget you can change the value using setState() to rebuild the widgets but what if you want a button in child widget that change the value in parent widget ? here you need to use provider to get full control.

**Note:** *this is as example but it has multiple uses. you can use it with Firebase auth or cloud Firestore.*